# Is there a pre-trained word embedding for english song lyrics?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, word2vec, word-embeddings

I'm working on a project where the dataset is English songs. So I need word embeddings which are trained on English songs.
If none exist, Could you please suggest one that matches for this use case?